# SQL - Merge / Update & Delete from existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table:

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   NULL NULL e1 
NULL NULL c1   d1   NULL
a1   b1   c1   NULL NULL
```

I want to run a query that would merge/update&delete the existing rows whenever at least one of the columns have a equal value (except when NULL = NULL) to result in the following table:

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   c1   d1   e1
```

Please note that there are no unique IDs in any of the columns as any could have NULL values.

Could you please assist?

## Edited:

If any of the columns do not share the same value, I would them to be a separate record; and this would not affect any other records.

For example, if row 3 was:

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   c1   NULL e2
```

then the desired output would be:

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   NULL NULL e1 
a1   b1   c1   d1   e2
```

since row 1 already has a e1 <> e2 (so is left as a separate record); and row 2 and 3 are merged since they share c1 as a common C value AND also does not have any columns with differing values (other than NULLS).

Another example:

If there was an additional row, row 4 (with the original table):

```
A    B    C    D    E
NULL NULL c1   d2   NULL
```

Then the desired output would be:

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   c1   d1   e1
a1   b1   c1   d2   e1
```

Comment: You should show a better example of data that summarizes to more than one row.

Comment: Also, how would you handle a case where row 3 in your sample data included the E value e2? Or the case where an additional row existed with a C value of c1 and a D value of d2?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a complete answer, but rather an answer that will help others understand the problem and hopefully help steer them in the right direction to provide the complete answer:

As I understand it, the fundamental problem with the scenario you describe is that we need something like `TRANSACTION` (but probably not `TRANSACTION`) which will somehow allow us to accomplish the following steps.

**Step 1.**

In the following table, take the first row and compare it to all the other rows.

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   NULL NULL e1 
NULL NULL c1   d1   NULL
a1   b1   c1   NULL NULL
```

For the first row, we find a match with the third row in column [A] and then we update columns [B], [C], [D], and [E], then we delete the third row - giving us the following table:

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   c1   NULL e1 
NULL NULL c1   d1   NULL
```

**Step 2**

We look at column [B] and find no matches.

**Step 3**

We look at column [C] and find a match so we update the current row (row 1). We are ignoring / not merging `NULL`s so we get the following table

```
A    B    C    D    E
a1   b1   c1   d1   e1
```

The problem with this is that `MERGE` operations do not work as described. By that I mean once a row is `MERGED`, we move onto the next row.

This is a fairly complicated process so I personally am not sure how to tackle it, just wanted to help explain the problem in a more "developer-friendly" way.

I would expect the answer to look something like this (I don't think you can actually use `isnull` in the `ON` clause):

```
MERGE Table2 AS target
USING Table1 as source
ON (isnull(target.[A], -1) = isnull(source.[A], -2) OR isnull(target.[B], -1) = isnull(source.[B], -2), etc.... )
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE
    SET target.[A] = source.[A]
```

and so on...